# AttributeError: 'CursoProgramacao' object has no attribute '_avaliacoes'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno sistema em Python de "site de cursos online", e existe um erro que, pelo menos pra mim, não faz sentido.

Segue o código:

```py
from src.site.classes_de_alunos_e_professores import Professor  # O único parâmetro do construtor dessa classe é o nome


class Curso:

    def __init__(self, nome, aulas, professor, preco):
        self._nome = nome
        self._aulas = aulas
        self._professor = professor
        self._nota = self.nota_media()
        self._avaliacoes = []  # Existe uma classe chamada Aluno que está em outro arquivo (o mesmo do Professor),
        # que omiti dessa pergunta por dar espaço a esse código que já é extenso. Se for necessário posto nos
        # comentários. O aluno pode avaliar o curso com uma nota float e sua 
        # avaliação cai (ou deve cair) automaticamente na lista.
        self._preco = preco

    @property
    def nome(self):
        return self._nome

    @property
    def aulas(self):
        return self._aulas

    @property
    def professor(self):
        return self._professor

    @property
    def nota(self):
        return self._nota

    @property
    def preco(self):
        return self._preco

    @property
    def avaliacoes(self):
        return self._avaliacoes

    def nota_media(self):

        if not self._avaliacoes:
            return "O curso ainda não foi avaliado"

        else:
            soma_das_notas = 0
            for nota in self.avaliacoes:
                soma_das_notas = sum(nota)

            media = soma_das_notas/len(self._avaliacoes)

            return media


class CursoProgramacao(Curso):
    def __init__(self, nome, aulas, linguagem, professor, preco):
        super().__init__(nome, aulas, professor, preco)
        self._nome = nome
        self._aulas = aulas
        self._linguagem = linguagem
        self._professor = professor
        self._nota = self.nota_media()
        self._avaliacoes = []
        self._preco = preco

    def __str__(self):
        print(f"Nome do curso: {self._nome}; Nº de aulas: {self.aulas}; Tipo: Programação; "
              f"Linguagem: {self._linguagem}; Professor: {self._professor.nome}; "
              f"Nota: {self._nota}; Nº de avaliações: {len(self._avaliacoes)}; Preço: R${self._preco}")


class CursoDesign(Curso):
    def __init__(self, nome, aulas, ferramenta, professor, preco):
        super().__init__(nome, aulas, professor, preco)
        self._nome = nome
        self._aulas = aulas
        self._ferramenta = ferramenta
        self._professor = professor
        self._nota = self.nota_media()
        self._avaliacoes = []
        self._preco = preco

    def __str__(self):
        print(f"Nome do curso: {self._nome}; Nº de aulas: {self._aulas}; Tipo: Design; Ferramenta: {self._ferramenta};"
              f" Professor: {self._professor.nome}; Nota: {self._nota}; Nº de avaliações: {len(self._avaliacoes)}; "
              f"Preço: R${self._preco}")


class CursoMobile(Curso):
    def __init__(self, nome, aulas, so, professor, preco):
        super().__init__(nome, aulas, professor, preco)
        self._nome = nome
        self._aulas = aulas
        self._so = so
        self._professor = professor
        self._nota = self.nota_media()
        self._avaliacoes = []
        self._preco = preco

    def __str__(self):
        print(f"Nome do curso: {self._nome}; Nº de aulas: {self._aulas}; Tipo: Mobile; SO: {self._so};"
              f" Professor: {self._professor.nome}; Nota: {self._nota}; Nº de avaliações: {len(self._avaliacoes)};"
              f" Preço: R${self._preco}")

    professor = Professor("Marcos")

    curso = CursoProgramacao("Python 3", 9, "Python", professor, 130.0)

    print(curso)
```

E o erro que recebo é:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Windows 10/PycharmProjects/desenvolvimento_cursos/src/site/classes_de_cursos.py", line 87, in <module>
    class CursoMobile(Curso):
  File "C:/Users/Windows 10/PycharmProjects/desenvolvimento_cursos/src/site/classes_de_cursos.py", line 105, in CursoMobile
    curso = CursoProgramacao("Python 3", 9, "Python", professor, 130.0)
  File "C:/Users/Windows 10/PycharmProjects/desenvolvimento_cursos/src/site/classes_de_cursos.py", line 55, in __init__
    super().__init__(nome, aulas, professor, preco)
  File "C:/Users/Windows 10/PycharmProjects/desenvolvimento_cursos/src/site/classes_de_cursos.py", line 10, in __init__
    self._nota = self.nota_media()
  File "C:/Users/Windows 10/PycharmProjects/desenvolvimento_cursos/src/site/classes_de_cursos.py", line 40, in nota_media
    if not self._avaliacoes:
AttributeError: 'CursoProgramacao' object has no attribute '_avaliacoes'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self._nota = self.nota_media()
self._avaliacoes = []
```

Você está chamando `nota_media()` antes mesmo de inicializar `_avaliacoes`. Dessa forma quando você cai na condição `if not self._avaliacoes`, é lançado uma exceção, pois `self._avaliacoes` não existe ainda.

Se além de verificar se a lista esta vazia, você também quisesse que verificasse se `_avaliacoes` já existe, deveria usar

```
if not hasattr(self, '_avaliacoes') or not self._avaliacoes:
```

Comment: Opa, deu certo. Editei também a estrutura da self._nota e mudei todas as classes que herdavam de "Curso". Mas agora deu outro erro. Sou novo aqui, então não conheço as regras de conduta direito. Devo abrir um novo tópico?

Comment: @Padawan_22 Se esta resposta resolveu o problema que está indicado na sua pergunta, você pode aceitá-la ([**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052)  como fazer isso). Em seguida, você pode [fazer outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) com a nova dúvida. Essa é a ideia do site: uma pergunta para cada problema específico (mesmo que estejam relacionadas, cada pergunta deve ser "auto contida"). Para mais detalhes, veja a página **[ask]** e a [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)